# Smart algorithm to randomize a Double in range but with odds

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin

I use the following function to generate a random double in a specific range :

```kotlin
nextDouble(1.50, 7.00)
```

However, I've been trying to come up with an algorithm to make the randomization have higher probability to generate a double that is close to the 1.50 than it is to 7.00. Yet I don't even know where it starts. Anything come to mind ?

Java is also welcome.

Comment: Do you have a particular probability distribution in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to not think about this problem in terms of generating a random number with irregular probability. Instead, think about generating a random number normally in a some range, but then map this range into another one in non-linear way.

Let's split our algorithm into 3 steps:

1. Generate a random number in `[0, 1)` range linearly (so using a standard random generator).
2. Map it into another `[0, 1)` range in non-linear way.
3. Map the resulting `[0, 1)` into `[1.5, 7)` linearly.

Steps 1. and 3. are easy, the core of our algorithm is 2. We need a way to map `[0, 1)` into another `[0, 1)`, but non-linearly, so e.g. `0.7` does not have to produce `0.7`. Classic math helps here, we just need to look at visual representations of algebraic functions.

In your case you expect that while the input number increases from 0 to 1, the result first grows very slowly (to stay near `1.5` for a longer time), but then it speeds up. This is exactly how e.g. `y = x ^ 2` function looks like. Your resulting code could be something like:

```kotlin
fun generateDouble(): Double {
    val step1 = Random.nextDouble()
    val step2 = step1.pow(2.0)
    val step3 = step2 * 5.5 + 1.5
    return step3
}

or just:

fun generateDouble() = Random.nextDouble().pow(2.0) * 5.5 + 1.5
```

By changing the exponent to bigger numbers, the curve will be more aggressive, so it will favor `1.5` more. By making the exponent closer to `1` (e.g. `1.4`), the result will be more close to linear, but still it will favor `1.5`. Making the exponent smaller than 1 will start to favor `7`.

You can also look at other algebraic functions with this shape, e.g. `y = 2 ^ x - 1`.

Comment: Nitpick: Are you using `<0, 1)` to mean a half-open interval (including 0, excluding 1)? If so, I've never seen that notation; I've always seen `[0, 1)`.

Comment: @gidds Ohh, this is interesting. Yes, I mean half-open interval. I'm pretty sure we used `<>` in school, i just looked in Google for education materials in my language and they all use `<>`. But Wikipedia uses `[]`, even in my language. I updated my answer, because `[]` notation seems much more standard worldwide. Thank you!

Comment: It never occurred to me that there could be other notations for intervals! It seems mathematical notation isn't much more standardised than many programming languages :-) (I guess it might still be worth spelling it out in the question, in case anyone else isn't familiar with that notation.)

Answer (score 3):

You should start by discovering what [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) you need. Based on your requirements, and assuming that random number generations are independent, perhaps [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is what you are looking for:

> a call center receives an average of 180 calls per hour, 24 hours a day. The calls are independent; receiving one does not change the probability of when the next one will arrive. The number of calls received during any minute has a Poisson probability distribution with mean 3: the most likely numbers are 2 and 3 but 1 and 4 are also likely and there is a small probability of it being as low as zero and a very small probability it could be 10.

The usual probability distributions are already implemented in libraries e.g. [`org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.PoissonDistribution` in Apache Commons Math3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/PoissonDistribution.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to 'correct' the random with a factor in the direction of 1.5. You would create some sort of bias factor. Like this:

```
        @Test
    void DoubleTest() {
    double origin = 1.50;
    final double fiarRandom = new Random().nextDouble(origin, 7);
    System.out.println(fiarRandom);

    double biasFactor = 0.9;
    final double biasedDiff = (fiarRandom - origin) * biasFactor;

    double biasedRandom = origin + biasedDiff;

    System.out.println(biasedRandom);
}
```

The lower you set the bias factor (must be >0 & <= 1), the stronger your bias towards 1.50.

Comment: It doesn't make values close to 1.5 more probable, it just makes the range smaller. For example, ff you use `biasFactor = 0.5` then essentially you pick a random number from `<1.5, 4.25)` range.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a straightforward approach. As you said you want a higher probability of getting the value closer to 1.5 than 7.00, you can even set the probability. So, here their average is (1.5+7)/2 = 4.25.

So let's say I want a 70% probability that the random value will be closer to 1.5 and a 30% probability closer to 7.

```
double finalResult;
double mid = (1.5+7)/2;
double p = nextDouble(0,100);
if(p<=70) finalResult = nextDouble(1.5,mid);
else finalResult = nextDouble(mid,7);
```

Here, the final result has 70% chance of being closer to 1.5 than 7.

As you did not specify the 70% probability you can even make it random.
you just have to generate **nextDouble(50,100)** which will give you a value more than or equal 50% and less than 100% which you can use later to apply this probability for your next calculation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I missed that I am using the same solution strategy as in the reply by Nafiul Alam Fuji. But since I have already formulated my answer, I post it anyway.

---

One way is to split the range into two subranges, say nextDouble(1.50, 4.25) and nextDouble(4.25, 7.0). You select one of the subranges by generating a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 using nextDouble() and comparing it to a threshold K. If the random number is less than K, you do nextDouble(1.50, 4.25). Otherwise nextDouble(4.25, 7.0).

Now if K=0.5, it is like doing nextDouble(1.50, 7). But by increasing K, you will do nextDouble(1.50, 4.25) more often and favor it over nextDouble(4.25, 7.0). It is like flipping an unfair coin where K determines the extent of the cheating.

Comment: yeah, I guess this is the simplest, clear & understable approach to this kinda use case..!